# Templates and implicit conversion prevention on constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class Foo, which is of type T. When I create an instance of T I want to ensure the constructor is passed the same type.

The compiler ensures this, except for the small detail of implicit conversion. I want to prevent these and I can't figure out if there is a good way to do so. Compiler flags are not a option here.

I'm actually trying to prevent implicit conversions from double to float as my Foo class is doing some interesting magic that blows up on said cast. Any suggestions?

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  explicit Foo(const T& x) {kBitCount = sizeof(T); }
  size_t kBitCount;
  size_t mySize(){ return kBitCount; } // Size used to demonstrate
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  short sh = 5;
  Foo<int> foo_int_from_short(sh); // I want this to fail
  std::cout  << "size:" << foo_int_from_short.mySize() << std::endl; // prints 4

  Foo<short> foo_sh((unsigned int)5); // I want this to fail
  std::cout  << "size:" << foo_sh.mySize() << std::endl; // Prints 2

  return 0;
}
```

Updated with solutions, C++11 allows for compile time checks

```
#include <limits>
#include <typeinfo>

#if __cplusplus > 199711L // If C++11 or greater
#include <type_traits>
#endif

template <typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
  // Prevent implict type conversions at compile time
  template<
       typename U,
       typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U, T >::value >::type
    >
  explicit Foo(const U& x)
  {
#else
  template< typename U >
  explicit Foo(const U& x)
  {
    // Assert on implict type conversions, run time
    if(typeid(U).name() != typeid(T).name())
    {
      std::cerr << "You're doing an implicit conversion with Foo, Don't" << std::endl;
      assert(typeid(U).name() == typeid(T).name()); // Or throw

    }
#endif

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alternative to Cameron's solution has a single constructor that fails at compile time if an incorrect type is used:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    template<
       typename U,
       typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, T>{}>::type
    >
    explicit Foo(const U& x) { ... }
};
```

and could be made shorter with a couple of standard aliases.

Comment: This works well on C++11, I ended up with typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U, T >::value >::type

Answer (score 5):

How about adding an extra templated constructor to gather the less specialized calls:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename U>
    explicit Foo(const U& x);    // Undefined reference error at link time

    explicit Foo(const T& x) { kBitCount = sizeof(T); }
    // ...
};
```

If you're using C++11, you don't have to create ugly undefined external errors either -- you can just use [`= delete`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default):

```
template<typename U>
explicit Foo(const U& x) = delete;
```

Comment: That'll do it. I ended up with a assert(typeid(U).name() == typeid(T).name(), which breaks the generic part a bit and pushes things out to runtime - but it works.